# Can't use library Hammer.js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am performing an app with gestures using hammer.min.js library on Windows using sublimeText3.

I downloaded hammer.min.js from https://hammerjs.github.io/ put it on my project folder and call it but it nothing happens. I tried to import hammer library using `<script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/hammer.min.js"></script>` on HTML5. Also tried installing hammer library with "npm install --save hammerjs" but nothing seems to work.

```
"HTML file: index.html"

<!DOCTYPE html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Prueba de Apps Web</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="screen.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="panelGestos"></div>
    <hl id ='info'> gesto ! </hl>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="gestos.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/hammer.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
"CSS file: screen.css"

body{
    background: lightblue;
}
#panelGestos {
  background: darkgreen;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  font: 30px/300px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#info{
    color: black;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```
"JS file: gestos.js"

var panelGestos = document.getElementById('panelGestos');

// create a simple instance
// by default, it only adds horizontal recognizers
var hammertime = new Hammer(panelGestos);

// listen to events...
hammertime.on('tap doubletap pan swipe press pinch rotate', function (ev) {
    document.querySelector('#info').innerHTML = ev.type + '!';

hammertime.on("panleft panright tap press", function (ev) {
    panelGestos.textContent = ev.type +" gesture detected.";
});
```

Using hammer library I want to get message "panleft gesture detected.", "panright gesture detected.", "tap gesture detected." or "press gesture detected."

Comment: Did you check browser's devtools? Is the JS file found or returning 404 error.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using `Hammer` within `gestos.js`, you need to make sure `hammer.min.js` has loaded **first** before `gestos.js`. Swap the order of the script files:

You have

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="gestos.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/hammer.min.js"></script>
```

When it should be:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/hammer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="gestos.js"></script>
```

Or, you can wrap the code in `gestos.js` in a callback to the window load event.

By the way, you should really check the console when you run into issues, as it probably would have said something informative like "Hammer is not defined".

Answer (score 1):

At the very begining thanks for your responses. I follow your tips and it worked for me after of trying something else. First I downloaded hammer library from `https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/tree/master/` and from `https://hammerjs.github.io/` and import them (one at time) to use all the library functions following Joshua's tip. I don't know why but it seems to be a problem with library from those links. Then, I tryied `<script src="https://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.js"></script>` using hammer web library and it was all! It worked to me. Sorry for large explanation but I'll hope it will help to anyone too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to wait till the loading of `hammer.min.js` completes. You are trying to call `new Hammer(panelGestos)` from `gestos.js` which is seems to be running before `hammer.min.js` is completely loaded.

Comment: See Joshua T’s answer. You say before it’s completely loaded, but script tags load synchronously. hammer.min.js doesn’t even **start** loading until gestos.js is done loading, which is the entire problem.